# Classification of homogeneous distributions

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, wave-equation

On page 92 of [these notes](https://web.math.princeton.edu/%7Eseri/courses/Analysis2011.pdf), there is a discussion on how to find the fundamental solution to the D'Alembertian operator. It is firstly proposed that $c_n(t^2 - |x|^2 )^{-(n-1)/2}$ may be a good candidate. Then the author says that we can use the homogeneous family of distributions $j_a$ to get a homogeneous distribution that agrees with the above function in $t>|x|$.

However, I am unable to find the definition of $j_a.$

Could anyone **give me a reference/clue** on what result we are using here?

Comment: These are Riesz distributions. They are mentioned in [these](https://mathoverflow.net/a/92893) [answers](https://mathoverflow.net/a/287514), with references. The main one is Gelfand-Shilov _Generalized Functions I_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In sergiu's notes that you referred to, $j_a$ is defined in Definition 3.2 on Page 65. See equation (134).

Comment: Thank you very much for pointing out! Somehow I have overlooked this.

Comment: No worries; that particular missing cross reference was already a small "bug" when I was a student 15 years ago.